# $T\in \mbox{End}(V)$. If $p|m_T,$ then there is a vector $v$ such that the minimal polynomial of $v$ is exactly $p$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be linear a linear map and let $p\in \mathcal P(\mathbb C)$ be a non-constant polynomial such that $p | m_T$, where $m_T$ is the minimal polynomial of the endomorphism $T$. Prove that exists $v\in V$ such that $m_v=p$, that is, such that the minimal polynomial for $v$ is $p$ (the minimal polynomial for $v$ is the lowest degree polynomial such that the family $(T^j(v))_{j\geq 0}$ is linear dependent, ie, such that $m_v(T)(v) = 0$)

My attempt:

Since $p|m_T$, we may write $m_T = ph$. Writing $V_p := \{v\in V: p(T)(v) =0\}$, we must have $V_p \neq \{0\},$ otherwise we have $p(T)(u)\neq 0$ for all $u\in V$ and, since for all $u\in V$ we have $0=m_T(T)(u) = p(T)(h(T)(u)),$ it must be the case that $h(T)(u) = 0 $ for all $u\in V$. But the degree of $h$ is less than the degree of $m_T$, which is a contradiction.

Ok, now we may consider $w\in V_p, w\neq 0$. It is true that $p(T)(w) = 0$ and since $m_w$ is the lowest degree polynomial satisfying the condition $m_w(T)(w) = 0,$ it follows that $m_w|p$. No argument can help me proceed here to conclude that $p|m_w$, because it may not be the case. I'm stuck at this point. I guess that the correct path should try to construct such a vector $v$ using somehow the irreducible factors of $p$, but i'm not sure how to proceed.

**EDIT:** I guess that I could solve it, I just need to formalize it properly. Since $p|m_T$, the idea is to write $m_T(t) = \prod_{i=1}^s p_i^{\ell_i}$ and $p(t)= \prod_{i=1}^s p_i^{k_i}$, where $0\leq k_i\leq \ell_i$ and each $p_i$ is a monic irreducible factor and relatively prime with one another. Using a lemma prior to the primary decomposition theorem and the notation $V_p=\{v\in V: p(T)(v) = 0\}$, we may write: $V_p = \bigoplus V_{p_i^{k_i}}$ and since $V_p\neq 0$, we may consider $0\neq v = v_1+\cdots + v_s \in V_p.$ Since $p(T)(v) = 0$ and every $p_i$ is relatively prime with each other, it must be the case that $p_i^{k_i}(T)(v_i) = 0$ for every $i=1,\cdots, s$ and $p_i^{k_i}(T)(v_j) \neq 0$ for $i\neq j$. Therefore, we may consider $m_1,\cdots, m_s\in \mathbb N$ minimal such that $p_i^{m_i}(T)(v_i) \neq 0 $ and $p_i^{m_i+1}(T)(v_i)= 0.$ Define then $0 \neq \tilde v = \sum p_i^{m_i}(T)(v_i)$. It is the case that $m_{\tilde v} = p$.

Is this correct?

Comment: I think that this is equivalent to the statement that every transformation with equal minimal and characteristic polynomials has a cyclic vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though your construction works, assuming I have understood what you mean. Presumably, $v_j \in V_{p_j^{k_j}}$ for all $j$.

---

An alternative approach:  it follows by the structure theorem for PIDs (which is what I assume you mean by the "primary decomposition" theorem) that there exists an invariant subspace $W \subset V$ such that $\Bbb C[T|_W] \cong \Bbb C[x]/m_T(x)$.  There exists a vector $\tilde v \in W$ (for instance, the vector corresponding to $x \in \Bbb C[x]/m_T(x)$) such that $p(T)\tilde v = 0$ if and only if $m_T \mid p$.

Now, consider any $p|m_T$; write $m_T(x) = p(x) q(x)$. Let $v = q(T)\tilde v$. Verify that the minimal polynomial of $v$ is exactly $p$.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I meant by $v_j$. Thank you for your answer, while solving the exercise I also tought that $v$ should be equal to $q(T)\tilde v$ as you suggest, but I couldnt prove that $m_v=p$. I will try it again

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $V^T$ has cyclic submodule $C \cong \mathbb C[x]/(m_T)$ and then
$h$ has order $p$ in it.

Here are more details:
[Cyclic Modules, Characteristic Polynomial and Minimal Polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1689786/cyclic-modules-characteristic-polynomial-and-minimal-polynomial?rq=1)